# Checking whether a given timestamp is more than two weeks old

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, datetime

I am trying to see whether a given timestamp is more than two weeks old or not. If it is two weeks old, then print out "Hello" and if it is not more than two weeks old then print out "World".

I have a variable declared as `uint64_t` which contains the timestamp in milliseconds.

```
uint64_t data_timestamp;
```

How do I check whether this timestamp is more than two weeks old and if it is two weeks old, then print out `"Hello"` otherwise prints out `"World"`.

This is the code I have which gives me the timestamp in milliseconds for two weeks back from the current date, which I then compare to see whether it is two weeks old or not.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    uint64_t data_timestamp = 1406066507000; 

    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto twoWeeks = std::chrono::hours(24 * 14);
    auto lastTwoWeeks = now - twoWeeks;

    auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>\
                    (lastTwoWeeks.time_since_epoch()).count();

    std::cout << "Time stamp in milliseconds since UNIX epoch start: "\
              << millis << std::endl;

    if (data_timestamp < millis) { 
        std::cout << "Hello"; 
    } else { 
        std::cout << "World"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I will be running this code on Ubuntu 12.04. What is a better way of doing this? Are there any improvements which I can do it here? In general, I need to check whether `data_timestamp` is more than two weeks old or not. If it is two weeks old, then print "hello" otherwise prints "world."

Do I even need to use chrono time here? There are `2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 1,209,600,000` milliseconds in two weeks, so a simple subtraction of that from the current should tell me what is more than 2 weeks old? right?

Comment: Of course, it bears mentioning that days are really only always 24 hours in timezones without DST.  Depending on where this is being run for, you're going to need to do quite a bit more complicated math, since presumably you want 2 weeks measured in _days_, not hours...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You're already using `<chrono>` (and just that), so you don't need `<ctime>`.  Including it anyway won't automatically allow compilation in pre-C++11 (if that was your intent here).

  Also, since you're using `uint64_t`, you must include `<cstdint>` as well.
- Each variable can be `const` since they're not being modified.  This would still be a good idea for ensuring const-correctness, even though the entire scope is within `main()`.
- The `\` characters for line-continuations are useless here; the wrapping still works.
- Since you're not needing to flush the buffer, `std::endl` should be replaced with `"\n"`.  This may also give you a slight performance boost.
- The "hello world" output can be shortened to a single-line ternary statement:

  ```
  std::cout << ((data_timestamp < millis) ? "Hello" : "World");
  ```

  Regarding this comparison: my tests give a signed/unsigned mismatch warning.  You have already given `data_timestamp` an unsigned type, so `auto` must be deducing a signed type for `millis` based on the function's return type.

  One way to fix this could be by changing `data_timestamp` to a signed type such as `int64_t`, though `<chrono>` may offer more appropriate alternatives to help avoid uncertainty for this.
- You don't need your own `return 0` at the end of `main()`.  The C++ standard should guarantee that the compiler will do this return for you since success is implied.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. In general what I was after do I even need chrono here? There are `2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 1,209,600,000` milliseconds in two weeks, so a simple subtraction of that from the current should tell me what is more than 2 weeks old? right?

Comment: @Webby: I think you would still need it if you needed the current time, plus it's still a replacement over `std::clock()` and such in `<ctime>`.

Answer (score 4):

You could make you code way cleaner by using some C++14 additions: the [user-defined literals for `std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Literals). Thanks to them, you don't have to care anymore about the underlying type of your duration data, you only have to think about the usual time units:

```
auto data_timestamp = 1406066507000ms;
```

Also, thanks to those user-defined literals, you can also simplify the definition of `twoWeeks`:

```
auto twoWeeks = 14 * 24h;
```

In order to do that, you will have to tell that you are using the stadard library user-defined literals for `std::chrono` since they are not enabled by default. Add this line in your code:

```
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
```

---

Considering your second question about whether you have to use `<chrono>`: you could probably use the old `<ctime>` module, but `<chrono>` is an improvement over `<ctime>`. Since you need to get the current time, `system_clock::now()` is as good as you are going to get.

Moreover, while using simple integers could have been sufficient to compute what you need, using the `<chrono>` types and durations make your intent explicit: when you read your code again, it is obvious that you are dealing with date and time. That aspect alone is really important since anybody reading your code will know what you are doing instead of wondering what do some integers represent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. One thing which I would like to understand is if I need to do the similar stuff which doesn't support C++11, then what will be the best way to do it? As I cannot compile this code in the project which doesn't support C++11?

Comment: @Webby: The biggest thing is that you'll have to go from `<chrono>` to `<ctime>`.  You'll also lose out on `auto` and user-defined literals, so you'll really have to rely on the compiler to eliminate unsafe comparisons and such.

Comment: @Webby `std::chrono` and friends are taken from [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono.html) that doesn't require C++11 to work. If you don't want to use any other library, use `<ctime>`.

Comment: @Jamal Yeah I understand that. I was trying to see what else I can use to write down the similar stuff in the code which is not C++11 portable.

Comment: @Morwenn Thanks for suggestion. If possible can you provide an example which uses `<ctime>` and does the same thing?

Comment: @Webby You could try it yourself and post a sequel question. That would be a good exercise.

Comment: @Webby: Given that the whole point of Code Review is to take code and make it better, and part of the point of Morwenn's answer is to suggest that `<chrono>` is better than `<ctime>`, providing a `<ctime>` example would be a bit outside the scope of Code Review.

Comment: @nhgrif sure, makes sense. let me try it out something and then I will post another question for quick cr.

Comment: @Webby: You could also tag that question as [tag:c++03] to make it clear that C++11 and above is not to be considered.